# How to Pre-fill custom form after error in form submission in Magento?

Tags: forms, magento

How can I get pre-filled form in case of mistake in filling some form  element(s) in Magento?

I have a custom module with form similar to contacts form but it has recaptcha. So the customer need to insert captcha code along with other required fields.

Suppose customer makes mistake in filling recaptcha, so they will be redirected to same page but I see the form data disappeared after redirection. So what I want is to preserve form fields so that they don't need to fill them again and again.

Any help will be greatly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way Magento can handle this kind of situation is through **sessions**.
Data stored in sessions will be persistent throughout requests and you'll be able to use these data later (after a redirection, page change etc....)

On the opposite, on a single request you can check out how to use Magento registry methods `Mage::register()`/`Mage::registry()`. Registry can be used when you need to keep data on the same request (no redirection) for instance on backend modules when using "**Save and continue**" button.

To use sessions: set some data in the customer (or another one if needed) session with :

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setData('myDataName', $myData);
```

For instance when data is posted and you are in some sort of postAction you'll store posted data in customer session.

For instance :

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setData('postedData', $post);
```

Then later on you can retrieve that data with

```
$myData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getData('postedData');
```

And then play with these data in your frontend form :

```
<input value="<?php echo $myData->getName()?>" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Grab the values by using:

```
$myParam = $this->getRequest()->getParam('my_param');
```

or use

```
$params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

and fill it in your form.

Comment: Danny, Thanks for trying to help but it didnt work. The solution is posted here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/237450/

Comment: Magentoforums is closed and redirecting to magento.stackexchange.com It would be great if you could take the time to make an answer with that information.

Comment: Here is archive version of that forum thread, which is now dead:
https://goo.gl/t5EhKg